# What exactly is family of circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

How is it defined? I know that it's a product of two equations, but what does it represent exactly?

Comment: There must be some typo or mistranslation. It is common to call a 'family of circles' a set of circles that share some common property, e.g. pass through two given points; however I don't understand what it means to say "intersection of two given points". The textbook would make sense if the words "the intersection of" are dropped, but the way it is - it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: The term "familiy" is often used interchangeably with "set".

Comment: Please, provide more context to your question. The expression "intersection of two given points" is unclear.

Comment: I think there's some value to answering the question that I think this was intended to ask, but the bit about the "intersection of two points" could confuse people who otherwise might benefit from the question and answer. Correct use of words is vital in mathematics! It seems likely this question's continued existence here could do more harm than good. I see it's already on hold; I wonder when it is eligible for deletion (if the author doesn't fix it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this picture can help? All of these circles have their centre on the perpendicular bisector between the two points (the axis $p_y$ here), and therefore the family of circles can be indexed by this line.

[image: maybe]

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but the name for a set of circles which share 2 common points.

For example $$x^2+(y-q)^2= 1+q^2$$ is a circle for each $q$ and each circle goes through points $A(1,0)$ and $B(-1,0)$. So this is a family of circles. If you made a picture you will get something like Arnaud draw.